# How to explain the super-linear speedup observed in GPU device with CUDA code?

Tags: performance, cuda, parallel-processing

I'm having trouble understanding the scaling performance of an embarrasingly-parallel computation on a Tesla C1060.  Running it using all blocks and multiple threads per block, I get a run time is about 0.87s.

However, if I run all iterations in only one block with one thread per block, the run time is up to 1872s, which is much longer than the 240x0.87s = 209s that I'd expect from just scaling down to using only one of the 240 streaming processors.

Instead, by using all 240 cores it seems I get more than 2000x speed up.  How could this super-linear speedup be possible; what other factors should I be paying attention to in my performance modelling of this system?

Comment: Re: close votes - I think this is actually a pretty useful performance-modelling question for GPU codes; I've tried to edit the question to bring that out a bit more.

Answer (score 5):

Launching a kernel consisting of 1 thread limits the kernel execution to 1 of 30 SMs. For each warp instruction issued only 1/32 of the execution units will be utilized. In addition instructions from the  same warp cannot be issued on back to back issue slots leaving at least 1/2 the issue slots empty. Additional slot will be empty for instruction dependency and memory latency leaving 2-4 x speed up. Let's assume a really pessimistic 2x. A rough calculation of possible gain would be

```
30x increase for using all 30 SMs
32x increase for using full width of the execution units
 2x increase for using issue slots and saturating memory system
= 30 * 32 * 2
= >1920x performance increase
```

You are seeing a 1872/.87 = 2152x difference. This is easily accounted for by the >2x due to empty issue slots and the fact that 1 warp per SM cannot saturate the memory system.

Comment: So, if I run single thread CUDA program, is it so that next instruction would not be issued before current instruction has finished executing? or is there any instruction level parallelism for single thread CUDA program?